# How would I make a generic sort option SelectOpt for all columns?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

Is there a more elegant way of writing this: (the code below compiles)

```
getModelSorterOpt sortOrder sortField = do
    case sortOrder of
        "Asc" ->
            case sortField of
                "id" -> Just   $ Asc ModelId
                "name" -> Just $ Asc ModelName
                "created" -> Just $ Asc ModelCreated
                _ -> Nothing
        "Desc" ->
            case sortField of                                                                                                    
                "id" -> Just   $ Desc ModelId
                "name" -> Just $ Desc ModelName
                "created" -> Just $ Desc ModelCreated
                _ -> Nothing
```

The main problem is that I can't use a variable instead of the "Asc/Desc" case. Something like the code below, fails to typecheck.

```
getModelSorterOpt sortOrder sortField = 
                case sortField of                                                                                                    
                    "id" -> Just   $ sortOrder' ModelId
                    "name" -> Just $ sortOrder' ModelName
                    "created" -> Just $ sortOrder' ModelCreated
                    _ -> Nothing
                where sortOrder' = case sortOrder of 
                    "Asc" -> Asc
                    "Desc" -> Desc
```

GHC says that it doesn't expect ModelId and ModelName to be a part of the same case since they're different types. Which I think is valid. However, `Asc ModelId` is the same type as `Asc ModelName`. How do I tell GHC that?

---

Hammar's initial answer works. This version still doesn't work:

```
getModelSorterOpt sortOrder sortField = do
        (sortOrder'' ::  EntityField Model a -> SelectOpt Model ) <- sortOrder'
        case sortField of                                                                                                        
            "id" -> Just   $    sortOrder'' ModelId
            "name" -> Just $    sortOrder'' ModelName
            "created" -> Just $ sortOrder'' ModelCreated
            _ -> Nothing
        where sortOrder' = case sortOrder of  
                    "Asc" -> Just Asc 
                    "Desc" -> Just Desc 
                    _ -> Nothing
```

I get the same error that `ModelId` and `ModelName` are of different types. Is this because `sortOrder''` is being used monadically?

Comment: Oh sorry @AndrewC . I forgot to mention this is code with Persistent (Yesod). Models are the Persistent entities and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving `sortOrder'` a type signature.

```
where sortOrder' :: EntityField Model typ -> SelectOpt Model
      sortOrder' = case sortOrder of 
                    "Asc" -> Asc
                    "Desc" -> Desc
```

[This compiles](https://gist.github.com/ahammar/10591992) using GHC 7.6.2.

Comment: If I modify this to: `sortOrder' :: Maybe (EntityField Model typ -> SelectOpt Model)` and modify the `getModelSorterOpt` function with a `sortOrder'' <- sortOrder'` before the `case` to add some exception handling the function fails to compile (`ModelId` and `ModelName` types are different). I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: @tanmaig: For the same reason GHC can't infer the type of `sortOrder'`, it will also have trouble inferring the type of `sortOrder''`. Using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, you can write `(sortOrder'' :: EntityField Model typ -> SelectOpt Model) <- sortOrder'`, which should allow it to typecheck.

Comment: I added a follow-up edit to the initial question describing the `ScopedTypeVariable` version that doesn't work. I'm still curious about how this doesn't work. There seems to be enough information about the type signatures for it to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your design a bit by putting the lookup keys in an association list. Moving data into data structures rather than control structures seems like a win. I'm also making some assumptions about your types (or types similar to them). Here are two options depending on whether or not you like/grok Applicatives:

```
module Sorting where

import Control.Applicative ((<*>))

data Field = ModelId | ModelName | ModelCreated

data Sorting = Asc Field | Desc Field

orderMap :: [(String, Field -> Sorting)]
orderMap =
  [ ("Asc", Asc)
  , ("Desc", Desc)
  ]

fieldMap :: [(String, Field)]
fieldMap =
  [ ("id", ModelId)
  , ("name", ModelName)
  , ("created", ModelCreated)
  ]

lookupSorting :: String -> String -> Maybe Sorting
lookupSorting orderName fieldName = do
  order <- lookup orderName orderMap
  field <- lookup fieldName fieldMap
  return (order field)

lookupSorting' :: String -> String -> Maybe Sorting
lookupSorting' orderName fieldName =
  lookup orderName orderMap <*> lookup fieldName fieldMap
```

Comment: Aren't the `data` definitions for `Sorting` just re-inventing the 'SelectOpt` type that persistent has in the first place? I was hoping a type signature definition could solve the problem. I'm sorry I didn't mention these are `Persistent` types.

Comment: Yes, they are just the minimal definitions necessary to make my standalone example compile. The important bits are separating the structure of the computation from the data and the monadic and applicative lookup functions. It should work similarly with the types from persistent.